# How to replace values in one columns with values in another column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to replace some values in one column with values with another column based on a few conditions.
My original table looks like this:

```
 StartTime        EndTime       Hours    Location
12:00:00         00:30:00        5.5       A
12:00:00         00:30:00       -4.5       A
13:00:00         01:20:00       -6.5       B
12:30:00         04:06:00       -12.1      C
12:30:00         04:06:00       -12.1      B
12:30:00         04:06:00       -12.1      C
```

I want flip the AM values to PM values (or add 12 hours) in EndTime if Hours < 0 and NOT -12.1.
For example, the second end time would be "12:30:00" PM because Hours is less than 0 but not -12.1.
However, when Hours is -12.1, I'd like to change the end time to the StartTime.

I was trying to do this with case when and timedelta but it's not working. Could anyone please help with this? FYI, here's what I tried.

```
 select 
   case when Hours < 0 and Hours <> -12.1 
   then dateadd(hh, 12, EndTime) 
   else StartTime end as EndTime,
   Hours, Location
from myTable
```

But even after running this code, I don't see any change. Also, if I replace the end time with a certain time value, not a value from another column, can I do something like this?

```
 select 
   case when Hours < 0 and Hours <> -12.1 
   then dateadd(hh, 12, EndTime) 
   else convert(time, '12:30:00') end as EndTime,
   Hours, Location
from myTable
```

But again, with this code, I don't see any change in my data.

Comment: What is the data type of `hours`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this do what you want?

```
select (case when Hours < 0 and abs(Hours + 12.1) < 0.01
             then dateadd(hour, 12, EndTime) 
             else StartTime
        end) as EndTime,
       Hours, Location
from myTable;
```

My guess is that `hours` is a floating point number and `12.1` is an approximation.  So this uses an approximation.